# Include a DLL in a Rust project

Tags: audio, rust, dll, microphone, portaudio

I'm developing a project in Rust. My current goal is to somehow get access to the user's microphone audio. For this, after my research, I conclude that the best way to do it is using a crate called "portaudio". It was after a few attempts that I discovered that the crate is not the "code", but rather a wrapper for a library called "portaudio".
There is however a problem: I don't want the user to have to install the library to use my program. So is there any way to include the DLL file in the rust project, as if it were an image, for example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure a portaudio wrapper is what you need? Depending on what you are planning to do, it would probably be better to use a crate like `cpal`.

Comment: According to the docs if you build the portaudio crate with Env variable PORTAUDIO_ONLY_STATIC set it will embed portaudio statically - have you tried that?